# Javascript prototype banals: inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

How can i override `this.property` at runtime and for each instance, without making a new class and eventually calling `doAnotherThing` on the parent?

```js
var ThridPartyObject = function() {

    this.property = 'value';

    this.doOneThing= function() { /* */ }

    this.doAnotherThing= function() { /* */ }
};
```

No luck with:

```js
ThridPartyObject.prototype = {

    property: 'myvalue',

    doOneThing: function() { // Override only this function and call the other
        return this.doAnotherThing();
    }

};
```

**EDIT**: forgot to say that `property` may or may not exists.

I need this because, in backbone.js, i have to define a custom property for all my model instances, and some function should act in a different way of original backbone ones. Here is how backbone defines a `Backbone.Model` ([`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) is from underscore.js):

```js
  var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    var defaults;
    attributes || (attributes = {});
    if (options && options.collection) this.collection = options.collection;
    if (options && options.parse) attributes = this.parse(attributes);
    if (defaults = getValue(this, 'defaults')) {
      attributes = _.extend({}, defaults, attributes);
    }
    this.attributes = {};
    this._escapedAttributes = {};
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
    this.changed = {};
    this._silent = {};
    this._pending = {};
    this.set(attributes, {silent: true});
    // Reset change tracking.
    this.changed = {};
    this._silent = {};
    this._pending = {};
    this._previousAttributes = _.clone(this.attributes);
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  // Attach all inheritable methods to the Model prototype.
  _.extend(Model.prototype, Events, {
      // cut
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

If the object is truly "third party," and outside your control, then the creators of it have chosen a pattern that is not compatible with prototypal inheritance (sometimes called the "closure pattern"). You will not be able to override, globally, any properties of `ThirdPartyObject` instances, because every `ThirdPartyObject` gets `property`, `doOneThing`, and `doAnotherThing` newly assigned to it at construction time.

In this case the only solution would be to create a new factory function wrapping the original:

```
function modifiedThirdPartyObjectFactory() {
    var x = new ThirdPartyObject();
    x.property = "myvalue";
    return x;
}

var mtpo = modifiedThirdPartyObjectFactory();
```

---

A pattern that *does* use prototypal inheritance would work as follows:

```
function ThirdPartyObject() {
    this.property = "value";
}

ThirdPartyObject.prototype.doOneThing = function () {
};

ThirdPartyObject.prototype.doAnotherThing = function () {
};
```

This pattern sets *instance* properties, usually data, in the constructor. Whereas *shared* properties, usually methods, go on the prototype. The original code made *all* properties instance properties, so there are no shared properties you can modify that would result in your changes being reflected across all instances.

Comment: Assuming the good one (the second...), how can i call doAnotherThing from inside doOneThing?

Comment: I did as your example (function override) and this completly wipe out the original class... meaning existing calls on instances do not work anymore...

Comment: Yes, as I said, if you cannot modify the original class, you will need to use a factory function.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually thinking about it backwards.

Prototype would be like the parent class.
It's not exactly-like the parent class in a class-based language (there are a ***LOT*** of differences).
But in this instance, for the sake of inheriting properties/methods, prototype would be the parent class.

When you make a `Foo`, `Foo` is the child, for all intent and purpose in your problem.
When you do this:

```
function Foo () { this.method = function () {}; this.property = {}; }
Foo.prototype.method = function () {};
Foo.prototype.property = {};
Foo.prototype.other_property = 3;
```

It's similar to saying:

```
PrototypeClass {
    public virtual property = {};
    public other_property = 3;
    public virtual method ( ) { }
}
Foo inherits BaseClass {
    public override property = {};
    public override method () {}
}

var foo = new Foo();
```

The `constructor` for `Foo` is overriding everything up the chain in the `prototype`, that has the same name.
When `Foo` ***doesn't*** have a method or a property inside of it, ***THEN*** it looks upstream, through its `inheritance/prototype` chain.

So if you want to override methods/properties of `Foo`, then you ***MUST*** override the instance of `new Foo()`.

Your options for that are pretty much just to build a wrapper around `Foo`...  ...like:

```
function FooPlusPlus () {
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.plus = function () { this.doSomething(); console.log(this.val); };
    foo.plusPlus = function () { foo.plus(); console.log(this.other_val); };
    return foo;
}

var fooPlusPlus = FooPlusPlus(); // ***NO NEW***
```

...or to create a function which simply extends a pre-existing object (whether it's a "class" or a "dictionary" or a function, or an array) with whatever added properties/functionality you want to extend them with:

```
var extendObj = function (subject, extensions) {
    var key = "";
    for (key in extensions) { if (extension.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        subject[key] = extensions[key];
    }}
}


var regularFoo = new Foo();

extendObj(regularFoo, { awesomeFunc : function () { if (typeof this.doSomething === "function") { this.doSomething(); }}, coolProp : "Bob" });
```

JS gives you the freedom to let anything inherit anything, as long as you aren't expecting strings or numbers to act like classes with custom data, without careful manipulation of the Core objects.